# Hiding rough whereabouts of a machine with IPv6, without using a proxy

Tags: privacy, geolocation, ipv6

Since I configured my smartphone Access Point Name (**APN**) of the type *APN protocol* from including the value `IPv4` to including the value `IPv4/IPv6`, generally all different addresses I got after restarting my smartphone about 10 times, started with:

> 2001:44c8:

`44c8` seems to me to stand for "Bangkok, Thailand".

Although the question might seem absurd;
Is there is any way, besides surfing through a proxy IP address, for hiding rough whereabouts of a machine with IPv6?

Comment: There is an internet tool called "whois".  Using that tool "whois 2001:44c8::/32" I can see that 2001:44c8::/32 is assigned to a specific ISP headquartered in Bangkok Thailand.  The IPv6 address is not allocated to the location, it is allocated to the company.  Of course if that ISP only operates in Bangkok, then "IP location databases" will discover that and act accordingly.

Comment: As I've already explained [on your previous question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224035/are-ipv4-more-intuitively-hard-to-track-than-ipv6): IPv6 is not really different to IPv4 in terms of location tracking. So why do you still focus on IPv6 here since relying on IPv6-only protection with a dual IPv4/IPv6 stack would not solve the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all of your provider's allocated addresses are within a certain geographical area, you cannot obtain another address unless you tunnel or proxy in some way.